Can't connect to samba on ubuntu 24.04
I just got a VPS server from OVH, installed Ubuntu 24.04 on it, and followed this tutorial: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#4-setting-up-user-accounts-and-connecting-to-share
Literally nothing else I have done there.
Now when I try to connect to it on MacOS (smb://vps-ip-address-here:445/sambashare) I'm getting: The server may not exist or it is unavailable at this time. Check the server name or IP address, check your network connection and then try again.
More or less the same thing happens on Android in "Cx File Explorer" app.
Even telnet vps-ip-address-here 445 shows Operation timed out.
UFW is disabled.
What's more, I have recently installed Ubuntu on a mini PC and followed the exact same tutorial, and everything worked right away.
What can I do to debug this?
EDIT: Mini PC got Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop version, and the VPS was installed through OVH web GUI.

Of course you installed samba on the server and configured it. Same with telnet. What version of Ubuntu did you install on the mini PC? Edit the question and add the info.

This is interesting question, not many resources can be found online. I updated my server today from Ubuntu 20.04 to 24.04. Samba config is the same, samba is accessible locally, but not from other PC on the network (the same timeout message). Telnet to port 445 or 139 doesn't work (from windows as well linux PCs). ss -tulpn | grep LISTEN gives that ports 445 and 139 are listening from 0.0.0.0. ufw is disabled, iptables is used, but flushed, so no rules. Still not accessible from outside, although smbd is running happily. Weird!

Strange, same problem here on Ubuntu 24.10. Samba is running, shares are listed by smbclient -L localhost, Samba is listening to ports 137,138,139,445, but I cannot access Samba from outside even with all firewalls disabled. How to fix this?

I bumped into the same problem after upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 24.04. ufw is disabled, I have iptables rules for years and didn't want to change them.
The culprit was that nftables with firewalld were enabled as default and samba ports were not allowed.
If you are like me and use iptables (or ufw) then after disabling nftables and firewalld, samba will be accessible again:
systemctl stop firewalld.service
systemctl stop nftables.service
systemctl disable firewalld.service
systemctl disable nftables.service

PS Ubuntu 24.04 doesn't have iptables service, so if you want to easily restart iptables after changing /etc/iptables/rules.v4 then install:
apt install netfilter-persistent
apt install iptables-persistent

Reloading new rules is done by:
systemctl restart netfilter-persistent.service
